# Opening .pot file using python polib: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, parsing, machine-learning, character-encoding

When trying to read in the images of a chinese character [dataset](http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/databases/handwriting/Download.html) (OLHWDBD1.1) for machine learning I've stumbled upon a problem. The files are .pot files, and I'm using a python module called [polib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib) which should be able to read in pot-files. The code I use is:

```
import polib

which_encoding = polib.detect_encoding('database/C001-f.pot', binary_mode=False)
f = polib.pofile('database/C001-f.pot', encoding='UTF-8')
```

According to the which_encoding variable's output the file's encoding is utf-8. However, when I run the code I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Changing encoding type to ASCII doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you try to detect some encoding and ignore this then (overwriting it with ```utf-8```)? Do you understand your two lines of code?

Comment: Yes I understand! Sorry for the confusion. I just used the which_encoding variable to check its value inn the debugger. Its value is utf-8. I edited my question. Maybe detecting encoding is a bit redundant anyway since the encoding is also shown in the output-error, but I'll leave it there for now. Thanks. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have unzipped the file? How do you know to set `binary_mode=False`? Do you know what the first few characters of your text file should be?

Which OLHWDBD1.1 file did you download, and what modifications did you make to it before trying to use polib?

Comment: Hi! The file I downloaded was Online Character Data (45MB) , listed under the 'Competition Test Data' section at the bottom of the page.  I don't know what the first few characters should be, and no modifications have been made to it before using polib. The binary_mode is set to true if a MO-file is decoded, false for PO-files. I can confirm that the file is unzipped. Should I have modified the file first?